# complex string - sql parse and find value

Tags: sql, string, parsing

This is gonna be very difficult I guess. I have been breaking my head on this. I am reading data from spring framework tables(a Java framework for executing batch). The data in a field is as mentioned below,

```
'{"map":{"entry":[{"string":["processingFilePath","\/opt\/edge\/ingest\/inbox\/62662.P.D11102015T125249.P.xml"]},{"string":["fileHash","ce0f5b55d4f0c8d5c3f8af99878a506f210870a2"]},{"string":"jobId","long":7},{"string":["fileName","62662.P.D11102015T125249.P.xml"]},{"string":["submissionType","P"]}]}}'
```

In SQL Server 2012 , 
I need to pick up the JobId value which is no "7" from above, and the filename "62662.P.D11102015T125249.P.xml" . Please send in your suggestions to parse this using sql.

Thanks, kannan

Comment: can you use C# or similar programming language? Are you parsing this in sql directly or in an application?

Comment: I can use c# or sql  , since I am using SSIS  and SQL server

Comment: then check this out: http://stackoverflow.com/a/6620173/1291428

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I parse JSON with C#?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6620165/how-can-i-parse-json-with-c)

Comment: Thanks for the info.. I am using c# now.